# Mocking a file content in nosetest

Tags: python

I am trying to mock a json file content in Python using nosetests but not able to do so. I have tried the approach here but that is not helping me mock the actual content. I have been able to mock only whether file exists or not but not the actual contents.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for mocking file contents.

````
   def test_store_cert(self):
        with patch("__builtin__.open",
                   mock_open(read_data="data")) as mock_file:
            assert open("path/to/open").read() == "data"
            mock_file.assert_called_with("path/to/open")
            pim_pam_integrations.store_cert("data", mock_file) ```
````